# Formatter Class not working properly

Tags: java, formatter

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;

public class CreateFile {

    final Formatter x;

    public void openFile() {
        try {
            x = new Formatter("testing.txt");
            System.out.println("File created");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("You got an error");
        }
    }

    public void addRecords() {
        x.format("%s%s%s", "20", "bucky", "roberts");
    }

    public void closeFile() {
        x.close();
    }
}
```

I am getting the error "cannot assign a value to variable x". I am not sure why the "final formatter x;" is not transferring.

Comment: Transferring? You've declared it `final`, it's initialized to null, and because it's final you can't reassign a value to it. That's all.

Comment: `final` means final, once you initialized it, you can not reinitialize it. By default `x` will initialized to `null` when you create an instance of `CreateFile`. remove the `final` from x

Comment: I love it when questions contain the phrase "_not working properly_..."

Comment: remove final keyword since you can not reassign it.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen be defalut it won't initialize. it will give compile time error

Answer (score 1):

The `final` keyword prevents you from reassigning variable `x`. You can either remove `final` keyword or do the initialization right in declaration:

```
final Formatter x = new Formatter("testing.txt");
```

However since constructor of Formatter throws an exception, so we need to assign indirectly:

```
public class CreateFile {

    final Formatter x = getFormatter();

    private static Formatter getFormatter() {
        Formatter res = null;
        try {
            res = new Formatter("test.txt");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        }
        return res;
    }
}
```

Comment: if they declare like this then `x ` won't be visible in other methods.

Comment: Are you really sure about that?

Answer (score 0):

**do like this :**

```
import java.util.Formatter;

    public class Test {

         Formatter x;

        public void openFile() {
            try {
                x = new Formatter("d:\\testing.txt");
                System.out.println("File created");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("You got an error");
            }
        }

        public void addRecords() {
            x.format("%s%s%s", "20", "bucky", "roberts");
        }

        public void closeFile() {
            x.close();
        }
        public static void main(String []args){
            Test t=new Test();
            t.openFile();
            t.addRecords();
            t.closeFile();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A variable that is declared as final and not initialized is called a blank final variable. A blank final variable forces the constructors to initialise it.

```
final Formatter x;
public CreateFile() throws FileNotFoundException {
    this.x = new Formatter("test.txt");
}
```

The reason your code is not working is You've declared it final, it's initialized to null, and because it's final you can't reassign a value to it.

Comment: Are you really sure when stating that "A blank final variable forces the constructors to initialise it."?